# JavaScriptSerializer value for i=3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, javascriptserializer

```
JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
object i = 3;
string sJSON =  oSerializer.Serialize(i); //"3"
```

The `JavaScriptSerializer` should serialize its parameter to JSON!

And the result is "3" ( which is *not* JSON)

What am I missing?

### edit

Ive written a mail to douglas crockford

3 is not a json object/text but json value.

so i think msdn should clarify the serialize method.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOh3X.png

Comment: How about `string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(new { i = 3 });`?

Comment: @M.Babcock this is anonymous type . its not what ive asked.  Why my example doesnt returns jSon Object ? ( event i i send him an object)

Comment: The JavaScriptSerializer expects to use properties and fields of the object it is serializing. An integer has neither.

Comment: sole values are indeed JSON. Valid JSON is either an object, array or value. Head to a modern browser and give it `JSON.parse("3")` and you will get the number 3 back.

Comment: @MattGreer JsonLint sais "3" is not valid json. I intednt to believe it

Comment: @MattGreer  http://i.stack.imgur.com/VOh3X.png  3 is not a json object but value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been said many times by different people, the output you are receiving is valid JSON.

From the [JSON Specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627) (the Introduction):

> JSON can represent four primitive types (strings, numbers, booleans, and null) and two structured types (objects and arrays).

and further (Section 2.1):

> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of the following three literal names:
>
> false null true

My interpretation of specification tells me that the case you describe here is more a JSON *value* than a JSON *object*.

Comment: **3** is not a json Object but a value thats correct.   oSerializer.Serialize() should get an object and convert it to pair value . it doesnt.

Comment: Passing the value 3 to `oSerializer.Serialize` does not provide enough information for the serializer to produce a key/value pair, so expecting it to do so is unreasonable. The goal of JSON is to have a way of representing values that can be used in Javascript and in javascript I can have 'var i = 3;' which is not an object or a key/value pair.

Comment: sorry for driving you nuts about that silly question but its annoying my mind :) Ive written even a mailk to cirk douglas for an answer. I know very well what json is. but msdn says that the serualize method :  `converts an object to a JSON string.` so... 3 is not Json String but Json Value. and I thought he should go into Exception for :" not supplying me a class structure"

Comment: sorry. that last comment was intendend to kieren first comment. see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You asked it to serialise the value 3, and it did.  That's exactly correct.

To be explicit: what exactly are you expecting to come out?  JSON gives name-value pairs.  The value "3" has no name, because the *whole object* is 3.

JSON is JavaScript *object* notation.  Pass it an object, and you'll probably get what you're expecting.

You can use an anonymous type as M. Babcock suggests: `new { i = 3 }`.

Comment: what exactly are you expecting to come out ? That If i pass him something which is not an object - and he cant do its main goal - to parse to JSON - so go into EXCEPTION

Comment: The integer value `3` *is* an object, and the JSON representation of it is the string `3`.

Comment: I understand that. but jsonLint says that **3 is not valid json**

Comment: 3 IS valid JSON.  This is how you evaluate JSON: `var p = eval("(" + contact + ")");` Obviously, `"(3)"` evaluates correctly to the input value, the integer value 3.  JsonLint is incorrect in this case, or it is assuming the string its parsing represents a class/struct rather than a single value.  Again, 3 *is* valid JSON.

Comment: **JSON is built on two structures:

A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.**

Comment: Look Royi, you asked the question, many people have now given you the same, correct answer.  If you don't like the answer, ask a different question.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, you will get the same result even if you use a different library such as Json.Net.

Comment: @KierenJohnstone http://i.stack.imgur.com/VOh3X.png 3 is not an object. maybe douglas is wrong.... I dont think so.

Comment: Douglas does not say that 3 is not an object.  He says that is not a "JSON-text".  He directly says it is a valid JSON value.  (I'm not sure if you saw the RFC - official spec - but a JSON-text is an object graph.  A JSON value is clearly valid JSON)